# MYSQL Trigger insert data into another table while using signal sqlstate

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger before insert to do some validation. If validation is not met, I would like to prevent insertion and insert data into another table. I have tried to accomplish this using `signal sqlstate` but when this happens a rollback occurs which doesn't insert the data into the other table.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger tr_example_before_ins before insert on example
for each row
begin
    if example.price < 10000 then
        insert into example_log(example_id, notes)values(new.example_id, "WORKED");
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    end if;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Is there anyway to stop the insert without using `signal sqlstate` so I could still insert data into another table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is sometimes called an "instead of" trigger. That is, it inserts to the table `example_log` but does not insert into the table that spawned the trigger, `example`.

MySQL does not support "instead of" triggers, as for example Microsoft SQL Server does: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-instead-of-trigger/

If the trigger is aborted, then all actions performed by the trigger, and the action that spawned the trigger, are also aborted. There's no way to commit some of them without committing all of them.

So your only option to do what you want is to insert into the log table from the client that ran the insert on `example`.